# Loop between worksheets - Write Over Error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a macro to get information from a worksheet to write that information to another sheet with specified conditions in vba.

But unfortunately I have an interesting problem with my codes.

I have given a range to the worksheets with Array, and wrote down the conditions.
So it should go with the specific order for "hcr1" and also "hcr2" in the codes.

If the values for WS_Name3, WS_Name4 and WS_Name5 are different, everything works perfectly and writes the data to their sheets.
But, if 2 of those values or all 3 are same, macro gets confused and writes the last values to every row.

Let's say if WS_Name3 and WS_Name4 are same, WS_Name5 is empty, the hcr1 value is always 20, which is WS_Name4 value.

Here is the all codes;

```
Sub Atama() 


Application.ScreenUpdating = False 


Dim WS_Name As String 
Dim i As Integer 
For i = 23 To 34 
    WS_Name = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6).Value 
    Worksheets(WS_Name).Activate 


    Dim Acik_is As Long 
    For Acik_is = Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1 
        With Cells(Acik_is, 10) 
            If .Value = "Devam Ediyor" Or .Value = "Revize Devam Ediyor" Then Rows(Acik_is).EntireRow.Delete 
        End With 
    Next Acik_is 
Next i 


Dim lRow As Long 
Dim lLastRow As Long 
Dim WS_Name2 As String 
On Error Resume Next 
lRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Acik", Worksheets("Egitim Bilgileri").Range("BR2:BR20"), 0) + 1 
On Error Goto 0 


If lRow > 0 Then 


    WS_Name2 = Worksheets("Egitim Bilgileri").Cells(lRow, 1).Value 
    Worksheets(WS_Name2).Activate 


    lLastRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(Worksheets(WS_Name2).Range("AA22:AA1100")) 
    lLastrow2 = lLastRow + 21 




    For Satir = 22 To lLastrow2 
        With Cells(Satir, 26) 
            If .Value = "" Then 
                WS_Name3 = Worksheets(WS_Name2).Cells(Satir, 16).Value 
                WS_Name4 = Worksheets(WS_Name2).Cells(Satir, 19).Value 
                WS_Name5 = Worksheets(WS_Name2).Cells(Satir, 22).Value 
            End If 



            Dim WS_X_Code As Variant 
            For Each WS_X_Code In Array(WS_Name3, WS_Name4, WS_Name5) 




                If WS_X_Code = WS_Name3 Then hcr1 = 17 
                If WS_X_Code = WS_Name4 Then hcr1 = 20 
                If WS_X_Code = WS_Name5 Then hcr1 = 23 
                hcr2 = hcr1 + 1 

                RowCount = Worksheets(WS_X_Code).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
                On Error Resume Next 

                With Worksheets(WS_X_Code) 
                    NextRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 


                    Worksheets(WS_Name2).Cells(2, 3).Copy 
                    Worksheets(WS_X_Code).Cells(NextRow, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 
                    Worksheets(WS_Name2).Cells(Satir, hcr1).Copy 
                    Worksheets(WS_X_Code).Cells(NextRow, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 
                    Worksheets(WS_Name2).Cells(Satir, hcr2).Copy 
                    Worksheets(WS_X_Code).Cells(NextRow, 4).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 
                    Worksheets(WS_Name2).Cells(Satir, 34).Copy 
                    Worksheets(WS_X_Code).Cells(NextRow, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 
                    Worksheets(WS_X_Code).Cells(NextRow, 6).FormulaR1C1 = _ 
                    "=IFERROR(IF(AND(R[-1]C="""",R[-1]C[2]=""""),"""",WORKDAY(IF(R[-1]C="""",R[-1]C[2],R[-1]C),(SUM(R4C4:RC[-2])/7))),"""")" 
                    Worksheets(WS_X_Code).Cells(NextRow, 10).FormulaR1C1 = _ 
                    "=IF(RC[-2]="""",IF(RC[-4]="""","""",IF(RC[-3]<>"""",""Üretim Tamamlandi"",""Devam Ediyor"")),IF(RC[-1]<>"""",""Revize Tamamlandi"",""Revize Devam Ediyor""))" 




                End With 
            Next WS_X_Code 



        End With 
    Next Satir 

End If
```

End Sub

New version of the codes starting from the "Satir" loop are below;

```
    For Satir = 22 To lLastrow2
    With Cells(Satir, 26)
         If .Value = "" Then
             WS_Name3 = Worksheets(WS_Name2).Cells(Satir, 16).Value
             WS_Name4 = Worksheets(WS_Name2).Cells(Satir, 19).Value
             WS_Name5 = Worksheets(WS_Name2).Cells(Satir, 22).Value
         End If


            Dim WS_X_Code As Variant
            Dim X As Integer
            For Each WS_X_Code In Array(WS_Name3, WS_Name4, WS_Name5)

                Select Case X
                    Case 0: hcr1 = 17
                    Case 1: hcr1 = 20
                    Case 2: hcr1 = 23
                End Select
            hcr2 = hcr1 + 1

            RowCount = Worksheets(WS_X_Code).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            On Error Resume Next

            With Worksheets(WS_X_Code)
            NextRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

                Worksheets(WS_Name2).Cells(2, 3).Copy
                Worksheets(WS_X_Code).Cells(NextRow, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Worksheets(WS_Name2).Cells(Satir, hcr1).Copy
                Worksheets(WS_X_Code).Cells(NextRow, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Worksheets(WS_Name2).Cells(Satir, hcr2).Copy
                Worksheets(WS_X_Code).Cells(NextRow, 4).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Worksheets(WS_Name2).Cells(Satir, 34).Copy
                Worksheets(WS_X_Code).Cells(NextRow, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Worksheets(WS_X_Code).Cells(NextRow, 6).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(IF(AND(R[-1]C="""",R[-1]C[2]=""""),"""",WORKDAY(IF(R[-1]C="""",R[-1]C[2],R[-1]C),(SUM(R4C4:RC[-2])/7))),"""")"
                 Worksheets(WS_X_Code).Cells(NextRow, 10).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[-2]="""",IF(RC[-4]="""","""",IF(RC[-3]<>"""",""Üretim Tamamlandi"",""Devam Ediyor"")),IF(RC[-1]<>"""",""Revize Tamamlandi"",""Revize Devam Ediyor""))"


        X = X + 1
        End With
        Next WS_X_Code


End With
Next Satir

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Either switch to looping over `Worksheets()` using the numerical index (1, 2, 3 and so on) or ensure that the worksheets have unique names.

Comment: The worksheets names are not always different. Sometimes they are same. And that's where the the problem begins. If the WS_Name3 and WS_Name4 values are the same ( which means they are the same worksheet ), then it should first have the hcr1 for WS_Name3 and write it's data acording to " NextRow ", then go to the WS_Name4 ( which is actually the same worksheet ), write with hcr1 again but this time for WS_Name4. hcr1 values are different for WS_Name3, 4 and 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your error is in the `IF` statements.

```
If WS_X_Code = WS_Name3 Then hcr1 = 17 
If WS_X_Code = WS_Name4 Then hcr1 = 20 
If WS_X_Code = WS_Name5 Then hcr1 = 23
```

You want to compare to the name, but it actually compares to the values, so if there are the same values it will go with the previous one, as you mentioned.

One way to fix this, is to use a counter like this:

```
Dim WS_X_Code As Variant
Dim i As Integer: i = 0

For Each WS_X_Code In Array(WS_Name3, WS_Name4, WS_Name5)
    Select Case i
        Case 0: hcr1 = 17
        Case 1: hcr1 = 20
        Case 2: hcr1 = 23
    End Select

'i.e
Worksheets(WS_Name2).Cells(2, 3).Copy
Worksheets(WS_X_Code).Cells(NextRow, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
'....

i = i + 1
Next WS_X_Code
```

Next time i suggest going through your code with `F8` then you hover over the variables and see the values.

Comment: Thank you so much man, this solved the problem. But unfortunately it caused a new problem :) with this change, after the "WS_X_Code" loop ends, and the "Satir" loop starts, it doesn't write the new hcr1 and hcr2 for the next "Satir".

Comment: What is it doing instead? Could you post the updated code?

Comment: New codes works for the first loop of the "Satir" perfectly. hcr1 and 2 works great. But unfortunately for the next loops of the "Satir", it doesn't write any data for hcr1 and 2. I've edited the question with the updated code.

Comment: Have you gone through the code with f8? its very hard to tell whats wrong with these little infomations.

Comment: I've done the F8 inspection and I found that, at the 2nd or 3rd or other loops of "Satir", the hcr1 doesn't restart from Case 0 I'm afraid. It stucks at Case2

Comment: Have you declared the counter like i did?  to give him the startup value `0`.

Comment: Thank you so much man. I missed the declaration like you said. It works like charm right now. :)